# How can the memory limit of Javascript UDFs be increased?

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a complex javascript udf that occasionally runs into this error. Usually, when there is a lot of input data.

```
JavaScript out of memory error: UDF thread memory limit exceeded
```

As described here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-js.html#memory

> JavaScript UDFs will fail if they consume too much memory. The specific limit is subject to change.

Now I would like to know:

- What is the limit?
- Can it be increased by the accountadmin?

Comment: The limit cannot be changed by accountadmin, you will need to open a case with Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the memory limit of UDFs cannot be increased by yourself, but - according to the link in your question - it is subject to change in the future.